# Possible to access/monitor tvOS system audio output?

Tags: ios, audio, tvos

I'd like to develop a music visualizer app for tvOS which has the ability to listen to whatever background audio is playing (like Spotify, Pandora, etc.).  Does anyone know if this is even possible on iOS/tvOS?  In other words, there would have to be some functionality that allows the system audio output to be treated like an audio input.

I imagine that it would be the same functionality as doing a screen recording capture, at least the audio part.

My goal is to be able to do this programatically (Objective-C) so that the user doesn't have to do anything, it just "works" out of the box, so to speak.

Thanks